# OpenGL independent rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, opengl-compat

I'm trying to draw these shaped bellow this this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4O0e.png)
[image]

Tried this code:

```
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.98f, 0.83f, 0.73f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (float i = 0; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {
        x = 100 * cos(i)-10;
        y = 115 * sin(i)+270;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glRotatef(-135.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.83f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (float i = p; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {
        x = 100 * cos(i) - 10;
        y = 115 * sin(i) + 270;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
```

But this is what I get:

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqi8X.jpg)
[image]

If I want to only use the glLoadIdentity and glRotatef for rotation, do you have any idea about how to fix it?

Note:
I don't want to use push/pop or translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rotate the object around its center and move the rotated object to its position in the world. [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) rotates the vertices around (0, 0). Draw the object around (0, 0) and  [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) to move the object to its position in the world:

```cpp
glTranslate(-10.0f, 270.0f, 0.0f);   
glRotatef(-135.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   
    
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.83f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for (float i = p; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {
    x = 100 * cos(i);
    y = 115 * sin(i);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}
```

Note, the matrix operations like `glRotate` and `glTranslate` specify a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.

---

If you are not allowed to use `glTranslate`, you have to rotate the translation vector (-10, 270) in the opposite direction. Use the trigonometric functions `sin` an `cos` to rotate the vector (see [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)). You need to invert the angle and convert it to [Radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) since the unit of `sin` and `cos` is Radian.

```cpp
float tx = -10.0f;   
float ty = 270.0f;
float angle = -135.0f;

float inv_angle_rad = -angle * M_PI / 180.0f;
float tx_rot = tx * cos(inv_angle_rad) - ty * sin(inv_angle_rad); 
float ty_rot = tx * sin(inv_angle_rad) + ty * cos(inv_angle_rad);  

glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   
   
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.83f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for (float i = p; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {
    x = 100 * cos(i) + tx_rot;
    y = 115 * sin(i) + ty_rot;
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}
```